# AIRKinect with Kinect for Windows on OSX 10.7.4

Tags: actionscript-3, air, kinect, openkinect

Im currently trying to get a new Kinect for Windows to run on OSX 10.7
with AirKinect 2. So far i had no luck.

Here is what i did until now :

- i used the code from http://as3nui.github.com/airkinect-2-core/
- on http://code.google.com/p/simple-openni/wiki/Installation#OSX 
  i did the "Install OpenNI the short way" method .... with no errors.
- i installed the https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect stuff.

Then i wanted to verify if the device works. I used this app http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:18425
but it does not recognize the device.

In FDT 5.5, i have a sample project which uses the AirKinect Native Extension/ane.

All it does is to check for 
        Kinect.isSupported() but i constantly get the following error:

Error #3500: The extension context does not have a method with the name applicationStartup.

Currently im stuck here. Are there any drivers missing? Anybody got AirKinect + Kinect for Windows on OSX 10.7 to work?

chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, confirm that OpenNI works correctly. It should come with some very basic non-AIR samples. If the samples don't work, there is probably something wrong with the driver.

As far as I can gather from the information on GitHub, avin2's branches of SensorKinect don't have support for the Kinect for Windows sensor yet. There is a pending [pull request](https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect/pull/2) which apparently adds the missing features. You can find a Kinect for Windows-enabled binary [here](https://github.com/shenberg/SensorKinect/tree/unstable/Bin).

By now, the OpenNI samples should work. Try your AIRKinect Test again. If it fails, consider using an ANE from the [AIRKinect development repository](https://github.com/AS3NUI/airkinect-2-core/tree/dev/bin) - the builds there are updated more frequently than in the main branch.

But keep in mind: Neither have I tried this approach, nor do I have the facilities to do so. I'm just naming some common problem sources and their solution.

Comment: it seems that the driver does not work yet. i got 

Device: PrimeSense/SensorKinect/5.1.0.25: The device is not connected!
Device: PrimeSense/SensorV2/5.1.0.25: The device is not connected!
Device: PrimeSense/SensorKinect/5.1.0.25: The device is not connected!
Device: PrimeSense/SensorV2/5.1.0.25: The device is not connected!

Comment: It's also a common problem that there is not enough USB bandwidth available to the device. Make sure that the Kinect is the only device connected to the USB controller. To be extra sure, disconnect all other USB devices from your computer, if possible, since it's often not obvious, which ports belong to the same controller.

Comment: it seems that the SensorKinect driver is the problem. i tried the binary but it didn't work. so either i have to write my own driver or stick with windows for the time being.